# Powering a power supply question

Tags: amplifier, photodiode

I purchased an amp for photodiodes from Amazon. It came with a 5v power supply. I am powering it with a 9v battery

[image]

Everything seems to be working okay, but when I measure the voltage leaving the power supply it reads -14 and +7 so I am wonder if the 9v battery is the correct way to power the unit.

[image]

Also there is a 5v terminal next to the diode and I’m not sure what it’s for. So is the 9v battery the correct way to power this and why is there a 5v terminal next to the diode. Your help experience and know how is sincerely appreciated. I tried to contact the seller but received no response.

Comment: Do you have a schematic for the power supply?

Comment: No I’m sorry I don’t. I couldn’t find any info after Google searches either.

Comment: I does say 5v -28v DC on the underside of the supply though

Comment: First, disconnect the power supply board from the PD board. Now apply power via your 9-volt battery and measure the outputs. If you don't get +/- 5 volts, either your board is bad, you have the wrong board, or it is not intended to take 9 volts. The fact that it says 5 -28 on the board is a pretty good tipoff that it's not the board you want. ONLY when you have a power supply which MEASURES +/- 5 can you connect it to your PD board. If you apply  a grossly wrong voltage you may kill the PD board. And, oh yes, you may well have killed it already.

Comment: Did you consider the current consumption ? A 9V battery will be useless if you exceed a few dozen mAh.

Comment: @Overmind *mA. Capacity is mAh. Current consumption is mA.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone’s input. I think I figured it out. I use the google translator app and read all the writing on the amp and the power supply. The writing revealed that the amp has a rating of 5 to 15 volts + or - .By the way the translator app works great focus your camera on the characters and there it is in English.

Comment: This does not answer your own question for future readers.

Comment: Good point, but the use of the app did provide a solution that may be applicable in other situations. If you’re a mod and you’re saying I should delete my answer I will be happy to do so.

Comment: No, please edit it and explain how you solved it.